# Can someone explain this generic syntax?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, action

I've done a bit of google on this and have not found anything to explain the syntax..

So I'm using `Action<T>` for a producer consumer where `Action<T>` is the consumer action to perform. I right clicked on `Action<T>` - 'go to definition' to see its definition and this is what I was shown

```
public delegate void Action<in T>(T obj);
```

Hmmm... I've been using generics for quite a while now and have not ever used nor seen the syntax of `<in T>`

Anyone got a nice summation to hand to explain the syntax and what it produces?

Thanks. D

Comment: Google also for contravariance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`in`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484) and [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) variance modifiers for generic types has been introduced in C# 4.0 to allow co and contra variance to generic types.

> For generic type parameters, the **in** keyword specifies that the type parameter is **contravariant**.
>
> For generic type parameters, the **out** keyword specifies that the type parameter is **covariant**.

---

And from [Variance in Generic Interfaces (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059) on MSDN:

> Covariance permits a method to have a more derived return type than that defined by the generic type parameter of the interface.
>
> Contravariance permits a method to have argument types that are less derived than that specified by the generic parameter of the interface.